# GCC message on deprecated global variable usage from a library

Tags: c, gcc, ld, pragma, deprecation-warning

I have a C static library with global variables.
My goal is to print a message at compile time to the user whenever global variables from the library are used in its program.

I tried to mark variables as `__attribute__((deprecated))`. But I need the user to be able to build even if `-Werror` is set.

Therefore I tried to add `#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wdeprecated-declarations"`, but it only seems active within the library, not if a user link with the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could employ linker instead as explained in e.g. [ninjalj's blog](http://ninjalj.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/your-own-linker-warnings-using-gnu.html).

Here's a short example:

```
$ cat myvar.c
int myvar = 0;
static const char myvar_warning[] __attribute__((section(".gnu.warning.myvar"))) =
  "myvar is deprecated";
$ cat main.c
extern int myvar;
int main() {
  return myvar;
}
$ gcc main.c myvar.c
/tmp/cc2uM5Vx.o: In function `main':
tmp.c:(.text+0x6): warning: myvar is deprecated
```

Comment: You cat `mycar.c` and `main.c`, but then you do `gcc tmp.c tmp2.c`, small mistake with the names?

Comment: @AlexisWilke good catch, fixed.